# AngularJS - $watch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, output, angularjs-digest

Here's my app.js

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.watchMe = 'hey';

  $scope.init = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.watchMe = 'changed!';
    }, 3000)

  };

  $scope.$watch('watchMe', function() {
     console.log($scope.watchMe)
  });

}]);
```

I thought, after 3 seconds, I'd see:

```
'changed!'
```

in my console.

Instead, I just see:

```
'hey'
```

I call my init() function in index.html, as such:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController"  ng-init="init()">
```

Why am I seeing this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){

  $scope.watchMe = 'hey';

  $scope.init = function() {
  $timeout(function() {
      $scope.watchMe = 'changed!';
  }, 500);

  };

  $scope.$watch('watchMe', function(newVal, oldVal) {
     console.log(newVal);
  });

}]);
```

you are using setTimeout method. Angular is not watching that event. use $timeout service of angular then you can see the expected result.

Read about angular digest loop and dirty checking for more detail.